# Error on create table with auto-incremented ID in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm kind of new to Oracle SQL and I have a problem that I don't understand when I create my tables with an id which is auto incremented (**GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY**).

Everything is good until a table with a foreign key that leads to a table that was created before, I get an weird error :

> A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary

Here is my CREATE script :

```
DROP TABLE detail_demande;
DROP TABLE demande;
DROP TABLE detail_depot;
DROP TABLE tournee;
DROP TABLE employe;
DROP TABLE camion;
DROP TABLE centre_traitement;
DROP TABLE entreprise;
DROP TABLE type_dechet;
DROP TABLE fonction;
DROP TABLE site;
DROP TABLE modele;
DROP TABLE adresse;

CREATE TABLE adresse (
    adr_id                  INTEGER      GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    adr_num                 NUMBER(4)    NOT NULL,
    adr_rue                 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    adr_cp                  CHAR(5)      NOT NULL,
    adr_ville               VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE modele (
    mod_id                  INTEGER      GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    mod_modele              VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    mod_marque              VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    mod_capacite            NUMBER      NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE site (
    sit_id                  INTEGER      GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    sit_nom                 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE fonction (
    fon_num                 INTEGER      GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    fon_nom                 VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE type_dechet (
    typ_num                 INTEGER      GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    typ_nom                 CHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    typ_niveau_danger       NUMBER(1)    NOT NULL,
    typ_tarif_forfaitaire   NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    typ_tarif_par_lot       NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE entreprise (
    ent_siret               NUMBER(15)   CONSTRAINT PK_entreprise PRIMARY KEY,
    ent_raison_sociale      VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    ent_adresse             NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL
                                         CONSTRAINT FK_adresse_entreprise REFERENCES adresse(adr_id),
    ent_tel                 NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL,
    ent_contact             VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE centre_traitement (
    cen_num                 NUMBER(3)    CONSTRAINT PK_centre_traitement PRIMARY KEY,
    cen_nom                 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    cen_adresse             NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL
                                         CONSTRAINT FK_centre_traitement_entreprise REFERENCES adresse(adr_id),
    cen_capacite            NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE camion (
    cam_immat               CHAR(10)     CONSTRAINT PK_camion PRIMARY KEY,
    cam_date_achat          DATE         NOT NULL,
    cam_modele              NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL
                                         CONSTRAINT FK_modele_camion REFERENCES modele(mod_id),
    cam_site                NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL
                                         CONSTRAINT FK_site_camion   REFERENCES site(sit_id)
);

CREATE TABLE employe (
    emp_num                 NUMBER(5)    CONSTRAINT PK_employe PRIMARY KEY,
    emp_nom                 VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    emp_prenom              VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    emp_date_naissance      DATE         NOT NULL,
    emp_date_embauche       DATE         NOT NULL,
    emp_salaire             DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    emp_fonction            NUMBER(3)    NOT NULL
                                         CONSTRAINT FK_fonction_employe REFERENCES fonction(fon_num),
    emp_site                NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL
                                         CONSTRAINT FK_site_employe     REFERENCES site(sit_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tournee (
    tou_num                 NUMBER(6)    CONSTRAINT PK_tournee PRIMARY KEY,
    tou_date                DATE         NOT NULL,
    tou_immat               CHAR(10)     NOT NULL
                                         CONSTRAINT FK_camion_tournee REFERENCES camion(cam_immat),
    tou_num_employe         NUMBER(5)    NOT NULL
                                         CONSTRAINT FK_employe_tournee REFERENCES employe(emp_num)
);

CREATE TABLE detail_depot (
    dedp_quantite_deposee   NUMBER(3)    NOT NULL,
    dedp_num_tournee        NUMBER(6)    NOT NULL,
    dedp_num_type_dechet    NUMBER(3)    NOT NULL,
    dedp_num_centre         NUMBER(3)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_detail_depot           PRIMARY KEY(dedp_num_tournee, dedp_num_type_dechet, dedp_num_centre),
    CONSTRAINT FK_detail_dep_tournee     FOREIGN KEY (dedp_num_tournee) REFERENCES tournee(tou_num),
    CONSTRAINT FK_detail_dep_type_dechet FOREIGN KEY (dedp_num_type_dechet)  REFERENCES type_dechet(typ_num),
    CONSTRAINT FK_detail_dep_centre      FOREIGN KEY (dedp_num_centre)  REFERENCES centre_traitement(cen_num)
);

CREATE TABLE demande (
    dem_num                 NUMBER(6)    CONSTRAINT PK_demande PRIMARY KEY,
    dem_date_demande        DATE         NOT NULL,
    dem_date_enlevement     DATE         NOT NULL,
    dem_siret               NUMBER(15)   NOT NULL
                                         CONSTRAINT FK_entreprise_demande REFERENCES entreprise(ent_siret),
    dem_num_tournee         NUMBER(6)    NULL
                                         CONSTRAINT FK_tournee_demande    REFERENCES tournee(tou_num),
    dem_site                NUMBER(10)   NOT NULL
                                         CONSTRAINT FK_site_demande       REFERENCES site(sit_id)
);

CREATE TABLE detail_demande (
    dedm_quantite_enleve    NUMBER(3)    NOT NULL,
    dedm_remarque           VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    dedm_num_demande        NUMBER(6)    NOT NULL,
    dedm_num_type_dechet    NUMBER(3)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_detail_demande         PRIMARY KEY(dedm_num_demande, dedm_num_type_dechet),
    CONSTRAINT FK_detail_dem_demande     FOREIGN KEY (dedm_num_demande)     REFERENCES demande(dem_num),
    CONSTRAINT FK_detail_dem_type_dech   FOREIGN KEY (dedm_num_type_dechet) REFERENCES type_dechet(typ_num)
);
```

And here is the error I keep getting :

[image]

P.S. : everything is created if I replace the GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY by a number with a primary key constraint, without any error.

Comment: The error is very clear.  Any column you reference as a FK has to have a PK or unique constraint/index.  And IDENTITY still requires that

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The default may be auto incremented, but you could still insert multiple rows with the same value. Set them as unique or primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table `enterprise` includes a foreign key (`REFERENCES adresse(adr_id)`) that points to the column `adr_id` that is not a key on the table `adresse`.

Add `PRIMARY KEY` when creating the table `adresse`, as in:

```
CREATE TABLE adresse (
    adr_id   PRIMARY KEY    INTEGER      GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    adr_num                 NUMBER(4)    NOT NULL,
    adr_rue                 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    adr_cp                  CHAR(5)      NOT NULL,
    adr_ville               VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
);
```

To put it simple, the clause `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` only defines how new values will be generated, but it doesn't define a primary key **constraint**.